# pulling computer names from a network by IP address using a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I have been trying to figure out for a few days now why my code is not working.
pretty much I have a list of IP addresses in a CSV file. from this list of IP addresses I want to obtain the computer name.  When I execute no matter what I get

Exception calling "GetHostByAddress" with "1" argument(s): "An invalid IP address was specified."
At line:3 char:35
+ [System.Net.dns]::GetHostbyAddress <<<< ("$foo[0]")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Here is an example of the CSV File and the code used:

CSV File

Value 
192.168.0.11 
192.168.0.12 
192.168.0.13 
192.168.0.14

The code being used:

```
$foo = import-csv  C:\test\test\test.csv 
[System.Net.dns]::GetHostbyAddress("$foo[0]")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE: Added a Trim() call to remove leading or trailing spaces if exist.

Remove the quotes and call the value property:

```
$foo = import-csv  C:\test\test\test.csv 
[System.Net.dns]::GetHostbyAddress($foo[0].Value.Trim())
```

To resolve all address:

```
import-csv  C:\test\test\test.csv | 
foreach-object { [System.Net.dns]::GetHostbyAddress($_.Value.Trim()) }
```

You can use the -as type operator to pass on only valid addresses:

```
import-csv  C:\test\test\test.csv | 
where-object {$_.Value.Trim() -as [ipaddress]} | 
foreach-object { [System.Net.dns]::GetHostbyAddress($_.Value.Trim()) }
```

Comment: In my box (seven + powershell 2.0) $foo[0].value or $_.value is always $null. i've create the csv from a copy&paste from the sample of the OP. Have you some hints? thks

Comment: Just double checked, $foo[0].value or $_.value works for me as expected. I see that you've used gc instead of ipcsv, could be the reason why .Value return nulls.

Comment: what your return after a $foo[0].gettype()?

Comment: $foo[0].gettype().fullname >
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Comment: All is working for me as expected except for the last address, it has a trailing space and doesn't pass through, updating my answer to fix this.

Comment: that's ok Shay.. I'm only stuck why my return is $null!!! I'm on seven with posh 2.0... I missing something...

Comment: yes. No object specified for get-member (translate from italian, take it as is :-) )

Comment: i can take a look at the csv file if you want.

Comment: copy&paste the sample in the question in notepad.exe and save it as aa.csv

Comment: -my fault shay... too many white space in the "value"! It works now! Sometimes I'm too sure in what I do!!! -thank for support.. +1

Comment: Thank you Shay this works perfectly. I knew there had to be a fairly simple answer to the problem, and the resolve all addresses helps me even more.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample file is right I suggest to do like this:

```
$foo = get-content C:\test\test\test.csv | ? { $_ -notmatch  "Value" }

[System.Net.dns]::GetHostbyAddress($foo[0])
```